How to use method extension in Maui xaml?
I have a Dto object:
public class SearchResultDto
{
  public bool IsOne { get; set; };

  public bool IsTwo { get; set; }
}

And I have a method extension:
public static class SearchResultDtoExtension{
  public static bool IsBoth(this SearchResultDto dto)
  {
    return dto.IsOne && dto.IsTwo;
  }
}

At my ViewModel I can successful use searchResultDto.IsBoth();
I want this extension use in xaml like:
IsVisible={Binding IsBoth()}

It does not work.
How can I use a method extension in xaml?
my code:
<listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="contracts:SearchResultDto">
            <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding **IsBoth()**}"


you can't bind methods in XAML, only public properties

Well, only public properties are bindable, methods are not. You would need to create another property that invokes the method, e.g. an auto-property. As a general recommendation, it's better to not use a DTO directly as a model class in MVVM. You should create a separate class for the model and then map between the DTO and the model. That way, you can extend and update the model according to your needs without changing the DTO.

As explained in comments you can't bind methods in XAML, you could instead use one of the two approaches:

Using a ValueConverter:

public class IsBothConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (value as SearchResultDto)?.IsBoth();


    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:IsBothConverter x:Key="isBothConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
...

 <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource isBothConverter}}" />


Using an auto property (like @julian suggested in comments) Both inside your ViewModel:
Note that whenever the property of type SearchResultDto changed we raise a property changed event for Both property also.

SearchResultDto dto = new() { IsOne = true, IsTwo = true };

public SearchResultDto Dto
{
    get => dto;
    set
    {
        dto = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dto));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Both));
    }
}

public bool Both => (dto is null) ? false : dto.IsOne && dto.IsTwo;

I see that you are inside a datatemplate, thus you have to ensure a correct Source and x:DataType when binding to Both:
 <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Path="Both", Source="..."}" />


Using a third auto property inside your model (this goes against mvvm pattern as the model and the view are not properly decoupled)

public class SearchResultDto
{
    public bool IsOne { get; set; }
    public bool IsTwo { get; set; }
    public bool IsBoth => IsOne && IsTwo;
}

 <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBoth}" />


Just a suggestion: Maybe also include a way how to do this without directly using the DTO in the View.

@Julian you mean without altering SearchResultDto class by adding IsBoth ?

Yes, because auto-properties usually aren't part of a DTO, since the idea of having a DTO really is just data-transfer and typically, the DTO can change over time. For example, the DTO could already have a flag or something called IsBoth but with a totally different meaning. Anyway, just a suggestion.

@Julian totally agree, the best is to follow the mvvm pattern

I was thinking about a dedicated model class, e.g. SearchResult, but this works, too.
